# UPDATE statement to update multiple fields in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to update multiple fields in SQL **using one line**.

Here's an example:

```
"UPDATE badgeownedbadges SET badgeID =(SELECT badgeID FROM badges WHERE badgename=%s) SET scoutID = (SELECT scoutID FROM scoutinfo WHERE firstname=%s AND secondname=%s)"
```

Take %s as an applicable variable

Comment: have you tried it? What happens when you do? You've got a missing comma between the field declarations by the way.

Comment: Updating all existing rows with this information doesn't seem useful.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: seems an odd thing to do though, why do you need to select the IDs based on the name? Names could even be duplicated - could be two scouts with the same name quite easily. Surely whatever application is feeding the data to the query should be capable of identifying the correct ID (based on user input if necessary, e.g. from a dropdownlist or autocomplete in a UI) and giving the ID direct to the query without having to go off and (potentially unreliably) lookup the correct ID based on the descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply separate the fields using comma's, as you would a `select` query:

```sql
UPDATE badgeownedbadges 
SET 
    badgeID = (SELECT badgeID FROM badges WHERE badgename=%s),
    scoutID = (SELECT scoutID FROM scoutinfo WHERE firstname=%s AND secondname=%s)
```